# updated spring-boot-admin-server-ui not working

Tags: spring-boot-admin

How to include ui-jar to project? I have tried something like below but did not work

```
<dependency>
               <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
               <version>1.4.6</version>
               <scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/spring-boot-admin-server-ui-1.4.5.jar</systemPath>
           </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey why are using `<systemPath>` out there.
Simply using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

will work

Comment: I am trying to customize my UI so want to use jar instead